# S4 class is not subsettable

Tags: r, r-s4

I am trying to write a subsetting method for an S4 class. I get `this S4 class is not subsettable` error whatever I tried.

Here is a minimal example:

```
setClass(Class = "A", representation = representation(ID = "character"))
setClass(Class = "B", representation = representation(IDnos = "list"))

a1 <- new(Class = "A", ID = "id1")
a2 <- new(Class = "A", ID = "id2")

B1 <- new(Class = "B", IDnos = c(a1, a2))
```

When I type:

```
B1@IDnos[[1]]
```

I get what I want:

> ```
> > An object of class "A"
> > Slot "ID":
> > [1] "id1"
> ```

But I want to get this by just writing something like: `B1[1]` or if not by `B1[[1]]`

From [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961842/how-to-define-the-subset-operators-for-a-s4-class/10961998#10961998) post, I got some idea and tried to mimic what author wrote. But it didn't work in my case:

```
setMethod("[", c("B", "integer", "missing", "ANY"),
          function(x, i, j, ..., drop=TRUE)
          {
            x@IDnos[[i]]
            # initialize(x, IDnos=x@IDnos[[i]])    # This did not work either
          })
B1[1]

> Error in B1[1] : object of type 'S4' is not subsettable
```

Following code did not work either:

```
setMethod("[[", c("B", "integer", "missing"),
          function(x, i, j, ...)
          {
            x@IDnos[[i]]
          })
B1[[1]]

> Error in B1[[1]] : this S4 class is not subsettable
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think your problem is your signature is too strict. You are requiring an "integer" class. By default

```
class(1)
# [1] "numeric"
```

So it's not actually a true "integer" data.type. But when you do actually specify an integer literal

```
class(1L)
# [1] "integer"

B1[1L]
# An object of class "A"
# Slot "ID":
# [1] "id1"
```

So it might be better to use the more general signature of

```
setMethod("[", c("B", "numeric", "missing", "ANY"), ... )
```

which would allow your original attempts to work

```
B1[2]
# An object of class "A"
# Slot "ID":
# [1] "id2"
```

Comment: Good catch.. Worked great. Thank you.