# Subset operator for S3 classes - how to detect [i] versus [i,]

Tags: r, subset

I am implementing a replacement for the subset operator in an S3 class. I followed the advice on

[How to define the subset operators for a S4 class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961842/how-to-define-the-subset-operators-for-a-s4-class)

However I am having a special problem. How do I distinguish in R code if someone wrote x[i] or x[i,]. In both cases, the variable j just comes back missing.

```
setOldClass("myclass")

'[.myclass' <- function(x, i, j, ..., drop=TRUE) {
    print(missing(j))
    return(invisible(NULL))
}
```

And as a result I get:

```
x <- structure(list(), class="myclass")
> x[i]
[1] TRUE
> x[i,]
[1] TRUE
> x[i,j]
[1] FALSE
```

I don't see a way on how to distinguish between the two. I assume the internal C code does it by looking at the length of the argument pairlist, but is there a way to do the same in native R?

Thanks!

Comment: See, perhaps, how `"[.data.frame"` handles arguments and `nargs()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From alexis_laz's comment:

> See, perhaps, how `[.data.frame` handles arguments and `nargs()`

Inside the function call `nargs()` to see how many arguments were supplied, including missing ones.

```
> myfunc = function(i, j, ...) {
+   nargs()
+ }
> 
> myfunc()
[1] 0
> myfunc(, )
[1] 2
> myfunc(, , )
[1] 3
> myfunc(1)
[1] 1
> myfunc(1, )
[1] 2
> myfunc(, 1)
[1] 2
> myfunc(1, 1)
[1] 2
```

This should be enough to help you figure out which arguments were passed in the same fashion as `[.data.frame`.