# R S4 Class / Object

Tags: r, subset, r-s4

I have an S4 class object:

```
    class(pred)
      [1] "prediction"
      attr(,"package")
      [1] "ROCR"
```

and pred has following columns

```
slotNames(pred)
 #[1] "predictions" "labels"      "cutoffs"     "fp"          "tp"          "tn"          "fn"         
 #[8] "n.pos"       "n.neg"       "n.pos.pred"  "n.neg.pred"
```

pred has around 10K rows. Now I want to get records which has predictions > 0.5

How I can subset this?

Comment: hello, try `unlist(pred@predictions) > 0.5`

Comment: Hi Brunel, Thank you for your reply. class of the output, of this command, is logical. However, i am expecting class of the subset to remain same as the class of pred. Also, I want to access all the columns, such as fp, tp, of the subset

Comment: you 'll need to create a custom subset function probably  check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961842/how-to-define-the-subset-operators-for-a-s4-class